# How to install new chandelier when impossible to fish wires?

Tags: electrical, lighting, installation

[image]. Want to run a brown external wire to point where I can hang chandelier.  I can’t cut thru beams.  Any suggestions for where to find wiring, etc.

Comment: Do the green splodges in your pic indicate where you'd like to run a wire? Is there some existing wiring at or near the bottom, near the curtains?

Comment: Is it an option to go along the ridge beam instead?

Comment: I’d use 500 series metal wiremold surface raceway, with the appropriate fan rated wire wiremold box.  500 series wiremold is a little hard to work with if you’ve never done it before, and it will have a learning curve, but literally every piece you need is made.  Find an electrical supply house, not a big box store for this, they will have the odd parts that the big box stores don’t carry.

Comment: @Tyson, can you run romex cable, individual conductors, or both inside that wiremold?

Comment: @JPhi1618 single conductor THHN.  It’s essentially “pretty” metal conduit.

Comment: @Tyson The reason I didn't suggest raceway here is you'll have some odd jig-jog angles to work around (note the beam at the bottom, which seems to jut out from the wall)

Comment: @Machavity I saw it.  They will better refine there green line when they get to figuring which wiremold pieces they need, but every kind of corner exists in 500 series wiremold.   The stuffs a bit difficult to work with tho... for this project it would almost be worth hiring an electrician that’s got wiremold experience.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have wires from where the green line starts, this should be simple enough, provided you're OK with some wires showing.

You'll want to buy

- A heavy-duty (fan rated) metal fixture box (octagon) and screws to mount it into the top beam. I would suggest you buy [a box with clamps built in](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Westinghouse-15-5-cu-in-Heavy-Duty-New-Construction-Ceiling-Fan-Saf-T-Box-0105000/204845564)
- If you didn't buy the box with clamps, buy a NM clamp that fits the knockouts
- Finally, buy the proper size wire in **armored** cable, as well as clamps to secure the wire to the beam

If you're wanting to add a switch, buy a surface mount metal box, switch, and switch cover

Comment: Thank you so much.  I think I will give it a try.  I’ll post pictures of my results( if successful) if not I’ll hire an electrician- and see if he can do better!